# Upload image to digital ocean spaces is returning bad request

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-s3, digital-ocean, digital-ocean-spaces

Here is my code to upload image to digital ocean from spring boot using aws s3 sdk

```
        AWSCredentialsProvider awscp = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(
                new BasicAWSCredentials("clientId", "client_secret")
        );

        AmazonS3 space = AmazonS3ClientBuilder
                .standard()
                .withCredentials(awscp)
                .withEndpointConfiguration(
                        new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("https://myproject.fra1.digitaloceanspaces.com", "fra1")
                )
                .build();

        byte[] byteImage = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(data.filePath.split(",")[1]);
        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(byteImage);
        ObjectMetadata om = new ObjectMetadata();
        om.setContentLength(byteImage.length);
        om.setContentType("image/jpg");
        String filepath = "/images/"+ System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";
        space.putObject("myproject", filepath, is, om);
```

but this is giving InvocationTargetException: 400 bad request

I am uploading from my local machine and i have set cors for *

what is wrong in this code